# How to add direct HTML tags in web page with C# with response.write and read from table in sql and show between table tags as tables data?

Tags: tags, html

is there any other ways?

here are my desired code in between of my HTML tags.

I **don't** want to use objects like **Panel** or **Gridview** or etc.
but I want to scripted in my code by using HTML
and connect to SQL server database table named "Quicklunch_menu"

```
<DIV id=sidebar>

<UL class=menu>
  <LI><A href="http://mesbahsoft.com/">Main Menu</A></LI>
  <LI><A href="http://mesbahsoft.com/products/">Products</A></LI>
  <LI><A href="http://mesbahsoft.com/pages/about">About us</A></LI>
  <LI><A href="http://mesbahsoft.com/pages/contact">Contact us</A></LI>
  <LI><A href="http://mesbahsoft.com/tracking/">Ask Question</A></LI>
  <LI><A href="http://mesbahsoft.com/news/">News</A></LI>
    </UL>
<DIV class=basket-head>
```

i want to read links and titles from table that these data exist in there (TABLE)
i write only this sample code to direct write to page
that i guess doesn't right way

```
  <% 

    Response.Write("<table>")
      For i As Integer = 1 To 4 Step 1
          Response.Write("<tr>")
          For j As Integer = 1 To 4 Step 1
              Response.Write("<tr>" + "@" + "</tr>")
              Response.Write("</tr>")
          Next
      Next

    Response.Write("</table>")
  %>
<%@ Import Namespace="System.Data" %>

 <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" 
        ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:cbtclips_irConnectionString %>" 
        SelectCommand="SELECT  Quicklunch_menu.* FROM Quicklunch_menu">
    </asp:SqlDataSource>


    <asp:View runat="server"> 
    </asp:View>

<%
```

Comment: How to add direct HTML tags in page with C# response.write and read from table in sql and show between table tags as tables data??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Q:How to insert your desired HTML code anywhere you want in your HTML
>   code?

A:by adding this code anywhere you want in HTML File between the tags (that IDE allow you):

```
<% Response.Write(Var); %>
```

that this Variable  **:  Var** is a public Variable in your Class in reson of accessiblility.

Like:

```
public string Var = "";
```

and this can fill by HTML tags in loops (like for) by retrieving Database Tables.

```
for ( int i ; i < DataTable1.Rows.Count ; i++ )
     for ( int j ; j < DataTable1.Coulumns.Count ; j++ )
           //read from datatable and fill string
```